# when loadUserByUsername is invoked? (spring security)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm learning `Spring Security` and I have few quick questions respect `UserDetailsService`:

1- When `loadUserByUsername` is actually called or invoked? After authentication? Only once per login?

2- After login, will Spring put the actual logged user into httpSession?

3- Which is the recommended way to populate the collection of `<GrantedAuthority>` of `UserDetails`?

1. Eagle fetch them so when loadUserByUsername is called, the returned user already has it's "ROLES"
2. Implement another custom filter like `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` populate after success login?
3. Neither of above…

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. It is typically called by an `AuthenticationProvider` instance in order to authenticate a user. For example, when a username and password is submitted, a `UserdetailsService` is called to find the password for that user to see if it is correct. It will also typically provide some other information about the user, such as the authorities and any custom fields you may want to access for a logged in user (email, for instance). That is the main usage pattern. You can grep the code to see exactly where it is called.

As explained in [the manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#tech-userdetailsservice):

> There is often some confusion about UserDetailsService. It is purely a DAO for user data and performs no other function other than to supply that data to other components within the framework. In particular, it does not authenticate the user, which is done by the AuthenticationManager. In many cases it makes more sense to implement AuthenticationProvider directly if you require a custom authentication process.

2. Yes. A `SecurityContext` instance is [stored in the session](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#tech-intro-sec-context-persistence) once the user has been authenticated.
3. If you need to implement a custom `UserDetailsService` then it will depend on your requirements and how they are stored. Typically you would load them at the same time as the other user information. It's not something you would likely do in a filter. As explained in the above quotation from the manual, if you are actually implementing a different authentication mechanism then you should implement `AuthenticationProvider` directly. It isn't compulsory to have a `UserDetailsService` in your app. You can think of it as a strategy that is used by certain built-in features.

Comment: I think the confusion comes from framework design. Both UserDetailsService and UsersDetails are not compulsory in app but so much code and configuration revolve around them that developers are forced to write code from scratch rather than extending an existing implementation. Rather than advising on implementing AuthenticationProvider directly, I wish designers would straighten up the class hierarchy (and class names) so that it is easier for developers to re-use the code that is already there .

Comment: That's easy to say, but hard to do in practice when you are dealing with many different requirements and a codebase which has evolved over almost a decade. Changing code which is already familiar to people who have been using it for years isn't something that should be done on a whim. Sometimes it's better to live with a few eccentricities.

Comment: Luke, don't get me wrong. I love Spring and use it all the time. I 100% agree with you. Being in charge of a mission critical system, I take code change very seriously. My comments are specific to UserDetails and UserDetailsService though. For example, AbstractDaoAuthenticationProvider could be added in hierarchy to provide an extension point for developers who don't want to use UserDetails and UserDetailsService. At present, the specialized name is given to the abstract class AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider and a generic name is given to its subclass DaoAuthenticationProvider.