# When should I override the configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) from Spring Security in a Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I'm learning about Spring Security in a Spring Boot app and I have a very simple example. And I see that if I comment the `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` there is no difference. If I use it or not I have the same output, and I need to login with the hardcoded credentials.

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

//    private final MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http
                .csrf().disable()
                        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                        .httpBasic();
    }

//    @Override
//    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
//        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
//    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

MyUserDetailsService class:

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private static final String USERNAME = "john";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "$2a$10$fDDUFA8rHAraWnHAERMAv.4ReqKIi7mz8wrl7.Fpjcl1uEb6sIHGu";

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        if (!userName.equals(USERNAME)) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(userName);
        }

        return new User(USERNAME, PASSWORD, new ArrayList<>());
    }
}
```

RestController:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

I want to know if implementing the `UserDetailsService` interface is equivalent with overriding the `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)`. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

### [UserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-userdetailsservice)

> UserDetailsService is used by [DaoAuthenticationProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-daoauthenticationprovider) for retrieving
> a username, password, and other attributes for authenticating with a
> username and password. Spring Security provides [in-memory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-inmemory) and [JDBC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-jdbc)
> implementations of UserDetailsService.
>
> You can define custom authentication by exposing a custom
> UserDetailsService as a bean. For example, the following will
> customize authentication assuming that CustomUserDetailsService
> implements UserDetailsService

The *UserDetailsService* interface is used to retrieve user-related data. It has one method named ***`loadUserByUsername()`*** which can be *overridden* to customize the process of finding the user. In order to provide our own user service, we will need to implement the *UserDetailsService* interface.

`loadUserByUsername(String username)` returns the ***UserDetails*** which is part of `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails` which consists of ***`getUsername(), getPassword(), getAuthorities()`*** methods which is used further for spring security.

We can also customize the `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` (here used as `new User(USERNAME, PASSWORD, new ArrayList<>())`) by implemeting the *UserDetails* interface.

Here, I am sharing the ideal way to use the UserDetailsService service

```
@Component("userDetailsService")
public class DomainUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DomainUserDetailsService.class);

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public DomainUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String login) {
        log.debug("Authenticating {}", login);

        if (new EmailValidator().isValid(login, null)) {
            return userRepository.findOneWithAuthoritiesByEmailIgnoreCase(login)
                .map(user -> createSpringSecurityUser(login, user))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User with email " + login + " was not found in the database"));
        }

        String lowercaseLogin = login.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return userRepository.findOneWithAuthoritiesByLogin(lowercaseLogin)
            .map(user -> createSpringSecurityUser(lowercaseLogin, user))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not found in the database"));

    }

    private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User createSpringSecurityUser(String lowercaseLogin, User user) {
        if (!user.getActivated()) {
            throw new UserNotActivatedException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not activated");
        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = user.getAuthorities().stream()
            .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getLogin(),
            user.getPassword(),
            grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

### [when loadUserByUsername is invoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10856176/10961238)

As described above, It is typically called by DaoAuthenticationProvide instance in order to authenticate a user. For example, when a username and password is submitted, a UserdetailsService is called to find the password for that user to see if it is correct. It will also typically provide some other information about the user, such as the authorities and any custom fields you may want to access for a logged in user (email, for instance)

### [In-Memory Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-inmemory)

Here you have used the static values for username and password which can be ideally configured using the [In-Memory Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-inmemory) as follow.

Spring Security’s `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` implements `UserDetailsService` to provide support for *username/password* based authentication that is retrieved in memory. `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` provides management of `UserDetails` by implementing the `UserDetailsManager` interface. `UserDetails` based authentication is used by Spring Security when it is configured to accept a *username/password* for authentication.

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService users() {
    UserDetails user = User.builder()
        .username("user")
        .password("{bcrypt}$2a$10$GRLdNijSQMUvl/au9ofL.eDwmoohzzS7.rmNSJZ.0FxO/BTk76klW")
        .roles("USER")
        .build();
    UserDetails admin = User.builder()
        .username("admin")
        .password("{bcrypt}$2a$10$GRLdNijSQMUvl/au9ofL.eDwmoohzzS7.rmNSJZ.0FxO/BTk76klW")
        .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
        .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
}
```

### configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)

This method uses `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` which internally use *SecurityBuilder* to create an AuthenticationManager. Allows for easily building in memory authentication, LDAP authentication, JDBC based authentication, adding UserDetailsService, and adding
AuthenticationProvider.

[How Spring Security add/configure AuthenticationManagerBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25948090/10961238)

> UserDetailsService interface is equivalent with overriding the
> configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)

**No**

Comment: Thank you for response! So in my case, I don't need to override configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) if MyUserDetailsService is annotated with Service?

Comment: Hello elvis, You can annotate `MyUserDetailsService` with `@Component` or  `@Service` and can use the *UserDetailsService* as shared above and remove the static username and password from it.

Comment: It is not necessary to override the `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)`

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not same.

User details service provided in the application as bean is registered with **global** authentication manager ([`details`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configuration/InitializeUserDetailsBeanManagerConfigurer.java)) and is fallback for all the local authentication manager.

Depending on application set up can have multiple local authentication managers. Each local authentication manager will use the default user details service configured with `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)`.

> When should I override the configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder
> auth) from Spring Security in a Spring Boot app?

You should override if you have different authorization/authentication requirements and would you like to plugin your own authentication provider  to satisfy the requirement or add any built in provider like ldap and in memory providers. You can also do it directly using http security bean shown below.

All the authentication providers are added to [`Provider Manager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.18.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderManager.html) and are tried until one is found.

By default without providing anything ( i.e. without user details service or without overriding  authentication manager ) you would have the default global authentication manager with auto configured user details manager ( i.e user password `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` implementation as configured in `UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration` auto configuration ).

So when you provide user details service application bean the auto configuration backs off and now your global authentication manager now is configured with the provided bean.

More details [`here`](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture)

[`Here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54603001/2683814) is the good explanation how it all comes together.

I would also like to expand little bit more on spring security authentication manager in general which is very easy to overlook.

As I previously noted there is global authentication manager and local authentication managers. There is special care to be taken when configuring each if needed.

This is explained in the java doc for the global authentication manager annotation.

> The EnableGlobalAuthentication annotation signals that the annotated
> class can be used to configure a global instance of
> AuthenticationManagerBuilder.
> For example:
>
> ```
> @Configuration 
> @EnableGlobalAuthentication  
> public class MyGlobalAuthenticationConfiguration {
>
>    @Autowired
>    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
>             auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
>                             .and().withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");}}
> ```

> Annotations that are annotated with EnableGlobalAuthentication also signal that the annotated class can be
> used to configure a global instance of AuthenticationManagerBuilder.
> For example:
>
> ```
>  @Configuration  
>  @EnableWebSecurity  
>  public class MyWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>
>     @Autowired
>     public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
>             auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
>                             .and().withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
>     }
>
>     // Possibly overridden methods ...  }
> ```
>
> The following annotations are annotated with EnableGlobalAuthentication
> EnableWebSecurity EnableWebMvcSecurity EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
>
> Configuring AuthenticationManagerBuilder in a class without the
> EnableGlobalAuthentication annotation has unpredictable results.

`EnableGlobalAuthentication` imports configuration `AuthenticationConfiguration` responsible for setting up the default configuration for global authentication manager.

`AuthenticationConfiguration` configures two key pieces to make the authentication manager - user details and authentication provider.

User details is configured using `InitializeUserDetailsBeanManagerConfigurer` and authentication provider is configured using `InitializeAuthenticationProviderBeanManagerConfigurer`. Both of required  beans are looked up in application context - that is how your user detail service is registered with global authentication manager.

`GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` and `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` are consumers of global authentication managers.

`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` can be used to create and configure local authentication manager (add new authentication providers) and also typically used to have different authentication/authorization requirements in application like mvc vs rest and public vs admin endpoints.

With spring security alone `@EnableWebSecurity` triggers the above flow as part of spring security filter chain set up. With spring boot the same flow is triggered by spring security auto configuration.

In spring security 5.4 version you can define http security as beans without needing to extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class. Spring boot will have support for this in 2.4.0 release.  More details [`here`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/23421)

```
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
      {
         http
            .authenticationProvider(custom authentication provider)
            .userDetailsService( custom user details service)
            .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `@Service` annotation which creates the bean of the `UserDetailsService` at the time of the component scan. There is no need to specify it again in the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`.

If you don't use the @Service annotation, then you can configure it manually in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` by over-riding the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

To switch off the default web application security configuration completely you can add a bean with `@EnableWebSecurity` as explained in the [spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) (section 4.10.1. MVC Security),

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(MyAuthenticationProvider);
        }
    }
```

The `@EnableWebSecurity` is a marker annotation. It allows Spring to find (it's a `@Configuration` and, therefore, `@Component`) and automatically apply the class to the global `WebSecurity`

> To switch off the default web application security configuration completely you can add a bean with `@EnableWebSecurity` (this does not disable the authentication manager configuration or Actuator’s security). To customize it you normally use external properties and beans of type `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (e.g. to add form-based login).
>
> ...
>
> If you add `@EnableWebSecurity` and also disable Actuator security, you will get the default form-based login for the entire application unless you add a custom `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.
>
> ...
>
> If you define a `@Configuration` with `@EnableWebSecurity` anywhere in your application it will switch off the default webapp security settings in Spring Boot (but leave the Actuator’s security enabled). To tweak the defaults try setting properties in `security.*` (see `SecurityProperties` for details of available settings) and SECURITY section of Common application properties.

Answer (score 0):

No, implementing the UserDetailsService interface is not equivalent to overriding the configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth).

If you override UserDetailsSeervice and verify the username and password by override loadUserByUsername(), in your case it is static values(I would recommend for static users use inMemoryAuthentication).

You need to Autowired UserDetailsService

```
@Autowired
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```

And

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}
```

this will tell your authenticationManager to use userDetailsService which is been implemented for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

*I want to know if implementing the UserDetailsService interface is equivalent with overriding the `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)`.*

**No, they are not comparable.**

> `UserDetailsService` is core interface which loads user-specific data. It is used throughout the framework as a user DAO and is the strategy used by the DaoAuthenticationProvider. *

and

> *AuthenticationManagerBuilder  allows for easily building in memory authentication,  JDBC based authentication, adding UserDetailsService, and adding AuthenticationProvider's.*

So it is evident that when you use `UserDetailsService`, it means you are using `DaoAuthenticationProvider` for fetching user details from your underlying database.

*NOTE:* `AuthenticationProvider` is an abstraction for fetching user information from different sources/repositories and validates if the retrieved information is similar to the one provided by users.

Let's see an example, the configuration looks like this:

```
@Autowired
YourUserDetailServiceImpl userDetailsService;
.....

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}
...
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider(); //a provider 
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService); //user details service
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder()); //you can add password encoders too
    
    return provider;
}
```

And `YourUserDetailServiceImpl` has to override `loadUserByUsername()` to fetch used details.

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) {
    final Account acc = accRepository.findByEmail(email);
    if (acc == null)
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Account not found");
    
    //this can be a custom Object of your choice that `extends User`
    return new UserPrincipal(
                acc.getEmail(), 
                acc.getPassword(), 
                acc.isEnabled(), 
                true, true, true, 
                acc.getEpsRoles().stream()
                        .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getName()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```